# ASP.NET WebAPI (message handler) - Why did Authorize attribute allow all request?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I created example about ASP.NET WebAPI and I use message handler to set principal. In controller class, i set authorize attribute for some method but all request is allowed??? Can anyone help me?
Thanks a lot!!!

AuthenticationHandler class

```
public class AuthenticationHandler : DelegatingHandler
{        
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;

    public AuthenticationHandler(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {            
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    protected override System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var accessToken = request.Headers.GetCookies("Authorization-Token");
        if (accessToken.Count == 0) 
        //requests have no token always go here and doesn't set principal!!!!
            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        var tokenValue = accessToken[0]["Authorization-Token"].Value;
        try
        {
            var token = RSAClass.Decrypt(tokenValue);
            if (token == null)
                return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

            var user = _userRepository.GetUserData(token);

            var identity = new GenericIdentity(user.Username, "Basic");
            if (user.Roles != null)
            {
                var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, user.Roles.Split(',').Reverse().ToArray());
                Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
            }                
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Factory.StartNew(
            () => request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized));
        }
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Controller class

```
    //when i try send anonymous request, it always allows to get data???  
    // Why authorize attribute not working
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrators")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetAll() {
        var customers = repository.GetAll();
        var customersDto = new List<CustomerDto>();
        if (customers == null)
        {
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Customer not found");
            throw new HttpResponseException(response);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var cust in customers)
            {
                customersDto.Add(mapper.Map<Customer, CustomerDto>(cust));
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse<List<CustomerDto>>(
            HttpStatusCode.OK,
            customersDto);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered setting a breakpoint in your handler and stepping through your code? Unless you've overridden the default behaviour of the `AuthorizeAttribute` it should be returning a 401.

Comment: FYI if you are using WebAPI2 then setting Thread.CurrentPrincipal is not sufficient.  You need to set request.HttpRequestContext.Principal

Comment: I set break point to it and have a comment in my code. With unauthorize request, this message handler always send it through. But what i don't understand is why authorize filter doesn't work. When i try to create check user in role properties in controller and debug, the property isAuthenticated of HttpRequest is true and the authorize role is NT Local system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in web api actually Authorize attribute is not working and it is more about asp.net mvc approach.

To enable your AuthorizationHandler in asp.net web api you need to add your handler. You should do there, where you map your routs - either WebApiConfig class or Global.asax.cs

Below is example of assigning authenication handler for all web api routes

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new AuthenticationHandler());

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "DefaultApi",...);
    }
}

enter code here
```